# Script type test vectors

Tags: address, script, address-generation

I'm looking for test vectors, assuming xpub or public key to derive various script type addresses out of it. Something along the line of https://bip32jp.github.io/english/  but not only for P2PKH, but all P2W and P2T types as well (ideally with P2SH types too). Is there a place to find them, or could someone post few of these vectors in the answer?